rxjs pipeable operator to be triggered on subscription
In rxjs, given any Observable we can do observable.pipe(finalize(() => some_cleanup()) to run some_cleanup in any case (error or completion).
I was wondering if there is the errrr.... opposite of it, like an initialize() to run some setup code upon subscription.
Like this:
new_observable = observable.pipe(
  initialize(() => setup_things()),
  finalize(() => some_cleanup()),
)

Later we can subscribe to new_observable conveniently without even wondering if we need to setup something beforehand.
One obvious use of it is to make some ui indication that the operation is ongoing:
new_observable = observable.pipe(
  initialize(() => loading = true),
  finalize(() => loading = false),
)

Since I don't know of anything like this initialize() operator (hence this post), I'm used to do:
setup_things();
observable.pipe(
  finalize(() => some_cleanup()),
).subscribe(...);

I always thought this is so assymetric.

While RxJS does not have a built in initialize() operator, you could build one and use it.
Here is a sample implementation:
// Create a function that acts a rxjs operator
function initialize(setup: Function) {
   return (source) => new Observable((subscriber) => {
       setup();
       return source.subscribe(subscriber);
   });
}

// Usage: 
new_observable = observable.pipe(
  initialize(() => setup_things()),
  finalize(() => some_cleanup()),
)

Please note: You can modify or customize your initialize based on your application needs or add a few parameters to take in etc.,

I believe you can use the tap operator to achieve this behavior as follows:
obs$.pipe(
 tap({
   subscribe: () => initalize()
 })
)

